# How to implement fixed header with logo and menu in antd (white theme)?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

Description:

I want to implement a fixed header with logo and menu in antd. I have followed this documentation: https://3x.ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-fixed
(yes, we are still on v3)
The demo shows it in dark background and the menu component is on dark theme. I need it to be on white background.

Problem Statement:

The menu component has some extra height when in light mode so as to account for the highlighted / selected menu item and it also has a bottom border. Because the header is fixed to top of screen, it has to span the full width.
The menu is under `Layout.Header` which applies some padding on its own.
The way for it to look like a full width header would be to have a border spanning it.
I considered adding a border to the `Layout.Header` but it looks broken (menu height is about a pixel more than the `Layout.Header` height.

Codesandbox for the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-platform-stackoverflow-x8tx6

I might be missing something. Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `background: '#fff'` in the **Header** styles.
2. Change the **Menu** theme to `light`

Preview : https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-frog-jd3gb